# Virtualbox host-guest network setup

Tags: networking, windows-vista, virtualbox

How do I set up a network between the Host and the guest OS in Windows vista?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for a way with VirtualBox to have a network of your guest, your host, and nothing else (what VMWare calls a "host-only" network")? I'm looking for that too, and I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: I'm hearing rumblings that perhaps there's a built-in option for host-only networking perhaps in the current version of the commercial VirtualBox? I'm using the 2.1.4 OSE version, as bundled with Ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: For Windows 7 host and Windows 7 guest, just configure a Bridged Adapter using the "Intel PRO/1000 MT Server (82545EM)" as adapter type in advanced settings. Good luck!

Answer (score 45):

Give the guest two network adapters, one NAT and the other Host-only.  The NAT one will allow the guest to see the Internet, and the Host-only one will allow the host to see the guest.

One of them also allows the guest to see the host.  I'm not sure which, but I know it works since I've tested web server stuff with it.  You just have to choose the right IP address, 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x.

Also, you may have to be careful about having File and Printer Sharing running on both adapters at once, since the guest will see its own name and conflict with itself.  I ran into this during install.

Comment: This worked best for me as I'm using Virtualbox through Vagrant, and want to avoid host-specific configuration as much as possible (i.e., internet connection sharing).

Comment: This is the configuration that I've been using recently and I wrote a blog post explaining it in a bit more detail. http://blog.xoundboy.com/?p=586

Comment: If you are getting an error "Invalid Settings Detected" go to system -> preferences -> add a network interface. Any default one will do.

Comment: @Engineiro thanks - for me it was File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks - Add new host only network (icon). Virtualbox version 5.1.22

Answer (score 17):

I've got a better answer than my first one.

Give the guest a single Host-only network adapter, and enable Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) on the host.  I've tried this on a Windows XP host with a Windows XP guest.

The guest can connect to the Internet.

The guest can connect to the host at an address like 192.168.0.1 (chosen by ICS).  --  Remember to allow the guest through the host's firewall.

The host can connect to the guest at an address like 192.168.0.22 (assigned by the DHCP service provided by ICS).

Comment: Host-only network adapter is a ton easier than port mapping.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I guess I'm being kinda dumb for reviving this thread, but how do I enable ICS? Is that a virtualbox feature?

Comment: @pedromanoel I added some instructions :)

Comment: @pedromanoel In windows 7, search "internet connections", go to `view network connections`, right click > properties on `VirtualBox Host-Only Network`, check `Allow other network users to connect...` in tab sharing. But by checking that, I made the internet connection on my host stop working, and the guest doesn't have internet either... I guess I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this on a Linux host. I've documented the steps I took in Ubuntu 9.04 [here](http://www.callum-macdonald.com/2009/10/28/virtualbox-host-to-guest-networking/).

Answer (score -2):

I don't run vista, but virtualbox should do most of the setup for you - all you need to do is assign an IP address, subnet mask, and (optionally) a default gateway to your guest OS, and it should just work.

Don't bother with any of the advanced network settings in the options for the VM - they're useful in some situations, but I've never had to use them, and I've been using virtualbox for some years now.

If you post the specific problem you're having perhaps I can help more. But your question is rather vague...

Comment: All I want is to see/connect to my virtual machine from my vista host. Isn't it s way with Dynamic IPs?