# How to setup APE server on windows

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualbox

Can any one help me set-up [APE Server](http://www.ape-project.org/) on windows machine... I have installed it in Ubuntu in Virtual Box. But can't access on host windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to enable the VirtualBox guest OS to network with the Host and presumably with the outside network too. Take a look at an earlier StackOverflow question that might help:

[Virtualbox host-guest network setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156/virtualbox-host-guest-network-setup)