# How to connect to a local host of a virtual box system in mother system?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I got a ubuntu installed on virtual box, I run a server on it.

I can access it through 127.0.0.1

But from outside system, I can't get the web service.

I used ifconfig command in that Ubuntu system.

In the eth0 blank, I saw two other ip: 10.0.2.15, 10.0.2.255

I tried both of them, and still can't work.

I'm using VirtualBox software.

How could I access that local host of virtual Ubuntu in my outside system?

Comment: check the first comment here http://askubuntu.com/questions/52147/how-can-i-access-apache-on-virtualbox-guest-from-host

Comment: @rishal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156/virtualbox-host-guest-network-setup I think this one is more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Read the VirtualBox manual :p.. You need to do some [port forwarding](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward). Most likely port 22 for ssh and you can tunnel the rest.. Oh, http is port 80, if you didn't already know that. On my "fresh" server vms all i need to do is `VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "http,tcp,,80,,80"` (NAT - if you're using Bridged, it shouldn't be an issue) and i can access the webserver on localhost:80 form the host machine. Make sure nothing else is taking up 80 (Skype, etc.), of course.

Comment: I have used a port, just omit it on my question, sorry.

Comment: You have NAT port forwarding set up for the guest in vbox? Are you using bridged?

Comment: I guess it must be NAT, how to change it to bride? I'm now goolging for solutions.

Comment: NAT should work just fine in most cases, make sure your firewall(s) is configured correctly.

Comment: I've find kind of solution in this post. And now trying it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156/virtualbox-host-guest-network-setup